# XMPP Registration failure

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I started to create an iPhone chat app using XMPP (using the robbiehanson/XMPPFramework available on GitHub). I am using a goDaddy VPS server, with openfire. On that I can able login and chat with the already existing users. But I can't able to register a new user through my app. But I can able to register a new user on the server through the Adium app, so I think its not the problem of the server settings.

During debugging I found that the supportsInBandRegistration method returns 0, so the registration methods are not executing.

I am using the following code for registration :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appDelegate.xmppStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:username];

NSLog(@"Support for registration %u ", appDelegate.xmppStream.supportsInBandRegistration );
NSLog(@"Attempting registration for username %@",appDelegate.xmppStream.myJID.bare);

if (appDelegate.xmppStream.supportsInBandRegistration) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![appDelegate.xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Oops, I forgot something: %@", error);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No Error");
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Inband registration check failed");
}
```

Can any one please suggest a solution for this.

Thanks in advance....